# Error while updating table value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have 2 tables: `table1` and `wp_posts`. The first one is a custom table, the second one a wordpress one.

I want to change all post types in `wp_posts` that match a criteria that the `post_title` is the same as the `headline` in the `table1` and that the `type_id` key equals 41.

I tried selecting those kind of posts

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.headline = wp_posts.post_title WHERE table1.type_id = 41
```

And I get correct posts back (I'm doing this in phpmyadmin).

So I tried with

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs' FROM wp_posts JOIN table1 ON table1.headline = wp_posts.post_title WHERE table1.type_id = 41
```

And I get an error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM wp_posts JOIN table1 ON table1.headline = wp_posts.post_title W' at line 1

The table look like this (roughly)

**table1**

```
headline  |  type_id
--------------------
Random    |  41
Random 2  |  41
```

**wp_posts**

```
post_title  |  post_type
--------------------
Random      |  post
Random 2    |  post
```

And I need to change `post` to `jobs`

```
post_title  |  post_type
--------------------
Random      |  jobs
Random 2    |  jobs
```

The names (`post_title` and `headline`) are unique, so there won't be duplicates etc.

What's wrong with my `ALTER` sql statement?

Comment: There is no update ...set ... from syntax.

Comment: Update syntax is `Update table set column=value where conditions `

Comment: I'm a beginner at mysql (actually I was thrown into it, not my field primarily), so I don't know the proper way to do it. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts JOIN table1 ON table1.headline = wp_posts.post_title
SET wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs' 
WHERE table1.type_id = 41;
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks. I'll accept it in 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

Change the update query like below

**Query**

```
UPDATE wp_posts
JOIN table1
ON table1.headline = wp_posts.post_title
SET wp_posts.post_type = 'jobs'
WHERE table1.type_id = 41;
```

Comment: This is the same as the above, but he was first, so I'll accept his. Thanks +1

Comment: @dingo_d : We both answered exactly at the same time. Anyway no problem.. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, but when you sort by oldest tab, his comes first... no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 0):

Update Statement pattern is :

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
[WHERE where_condition]
[ORDER BY ...]
[LIMIT row_count]
```

The error thrown is caused by your 'FROM' key word.

You cannot ask for an update and in the same time use the SELECT Pattern data.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME = 'MY CUSTOM DATA' 
WHERE TABLE_NAME.[OTHER]COLUMN_NAME = 'MY PATTERN DATA';
```

MYSQL Link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into it.